# video capture in metro app

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I am currently developing video chat application for windows 8 tablet windows 8 tablet using Visual Studio Express for Windows 8 IDE. I am not able to capture streams using MediaCapture. I want to capture video in CaptureElement and then for testing purpose display it in mediaelement. I basically want to convert IRandomAccessStream into bytes and then vice versa in mediaelement. The following is my code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    MediaCapture mediaCapture;
    IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream;


    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
        randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

    }


    /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

    }


     async private void startCapture(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {

         await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();
         capturePreview.Source = mediaCapture;

         MediaEncodingProfile profile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWmv(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto);
             await mediaCapture.StartRecordToStreamAsync(profile, randomAccessStream);



     }

     async private void stopCapture(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         await mediaCapture.StopRecordAsync();
         await randomAccessStream.FlushAsync();

         randomAccessStream.Seek(0);

         // want to convert this randomAccessStream into byte[]
         mediaElement.SetSource(randomAccessStream, "video/x-ms-wmv");

     }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below code and its working fine for me. Only added code in events.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    MediaCapture mediaCapture;
    IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
        randomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
    /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private async void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();

        MediaEncodingProfile profile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWmv(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto);
        await mediaCapture.StartRecordToStreamAsync(profile, randomAccessStream);
    }

    private async void StropButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await mediaCapture.StopRecordAsync();
        await randomAccessStream.FlushAsync();

        randomAccessStream.Seek(0);

        // want to convert this randomAccessStream into byte[]
        mediaElement.SetSource(randomAccessStream, "video/x-ms-wmv");
    }
}
```